# NSPredicate - Unable to generate SQL for predicate, I wonder why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate

I have already solved my problem [Blindly] without understanding root cause. But I would rather understand a concept from a professional. So could you please tell me why below identical code one works but another doesn't.

**Code 1: Doesn't work**

```
//Above code omitted...

NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gender == m"]; //NOTICE HERE
[request setPredicate:predicate];   
NSError *error = nil;
self.people = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

 //Below code omitted...
```

**Code 2: Does work**

```
//Above code omitted...

NSString *type = @"m";    
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gender == %@",type]; //NOTICE HERE
[request setPredicate:predicate];   
NSError *error = nil;
self.people = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

//Below code omitted...
```

---

Forgot to tell about what error I got, I got SIGABRT on below line, When I executed Code 1.

```
 self.people = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

And one more thing, in GCC error was it cannot format predicate because of "gender == m".

---

Enlighten me!!

Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your title to be a bit more explanatory? It might help get some more answers :-)

Comment: @kalaracey, How about this one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the [predicate programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795) (heading "Literals"). You can use literals in your string but you have to enclose them in quotes, so

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gender == 'm'"];
```

Would have worked. When predicateWithFormat adds in the argument, it knows it is a string. When you just have **m** in there, it doesn't know what to do with it, hence the error.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot. I should more concentrate while reading documentation :( lol

Answer (score 1):

> **example with swift**

```
let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Words")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "letter == '\(letter)'")
        var error: NSError?
        let fetchedResults =
        managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
            error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]
        if let results = fetchedResults {
                       println(results)
        } else {
            println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
```